# POSTGRESQL HOW TO DISTINCT Fullwidth

Tags: postgresql

I have data in my dataset like below,in varchar data type.

```
123456789X
123456789x
123456789x
１２３４５６７８９X
```

Please advise how to use distinct lower to distinct above 4 to 1? Thanks.

I found how to solve this problem by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TRANSLATE(LOWER(telephone),
'－０１２３４５６７８９ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ',
'-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
```

Comment: sorry ,there is no prefix.I removed them.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TRANSLATE(LOWER(telephone),
'－０１２３４５６７８９ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ',
'-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not**  a function. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a`. And `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the spaces (using `replace`) and then apply `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(data, ' ', '')
FROM   mytable
```